# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed because of models.DO_NOTHING

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I have this snippet of code for models.py

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    provider = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

when ever I tried to delete an object I faced an error says :

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

I faced this issue on django 2.x , since every thing was perfect on 1.11.
I made a little search I found may this issue happen by this part `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING`, So how could I fix it with kepping every thing as it is ?

Comment: How do you remove an object?

Comment: by admin panel  (localhost/admin)

Answer (score 3):

Basically you're telling Django to do nothing when you delete a user. So you will try to delete the row which has a related foreign key, this is expected behavior.
If you want to keep the provider model even when the user got deleted you have to make user nullable and use models.SET_NULL.
If provider has non sense in your logic you can then cascade.
If you need to reassign to a default user you can use custom method.

Comment: That make sense, but why it was perfect on django 1.x ?, what if I want keep user as text just like django 1.x ?

Comment: I do not think that was working, it only means there was no database constraint enforced, for example with myIsam mysql database

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DO_NOTHING